# How do you refresh data in an observable array list?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, observablecollection

I have created multiple observable array lists in the public class.

```
ObservableList<PieChart.Data> q1ChartData =
                    FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                            new PieChart.Data("Strongly Agree", s1sa),
                            new PieChart.Data("Agree", s1a),
                            new PieChart.Data("Neither", s1naod),
                            new PieChart.Data("Disagree", s1d),
                            new PieChart.Data("Strongly Disagree", s1sd));
```

Whereby s1sa,s1a,s1naod etc. are integers that are constantly changing from user input. I then want to use this data to create a pie chart but it when i do this using a event handler when a button is pressed the data is still 0. Is there anyway of refreshing the array list or a different way that I can do this?
Thank you very much

Comment: In order for updates to occur via notification events, you need to define your data model using JavaFX Bean conventions, i.e. with a setter, getter, and a property accessor.  Have you done this with PieChart.Data?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a PieChart.Data constructor that accepts an integer...

The constructor should be:

```
PieChart.Data(java.lang.String name, double value)
```

I Think what you're describing is a binding, if I'm understanding what you want. In which case, you'll need to change the type of your variables slightly. If you still wanted them to represent Integers it should be something like the following.

```
    IntegerProperty s1sa = new SimpleIntegerProperty(1);

    PieChart.Data data = new PieChart.Data("Strongly Agree", s1sa.doubleValue());

    data.pieValueProperty().bind(s1sa);
```

Binding it this way, any change to s1sa will automatically update your data.

For more info on Bindings: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm